# SMTP Gmail response in C#

Tags: c#, smtp

in using Gmail as SMTP mailing service, do i get any exception if i send a message to an email that doesn't exists?

```
 try
 {
    smtpserver.Send(MailMessage);
 }
 catch (SmtpFailedRecipientException ex)
 {
    // when does this exception occur?
 }
```

what exception do i need to catch if the mail has not been sent to an email that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

smtp servers dont know if an target address exists. the receiving server sends an message back to you, if the address is unknown.